# SimpleModal content only appears on page resize

Tags: javascript, resize, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal to pop up a modal on my page. I'm hiding the modal content on page load with display:none. I have the simplemodal-container styled properly, and that pops up fine. The content that's supposed to be in the container, though, remains undisplayed; unless I resize the page. When I do resize it, the content appears just as I want it to.

How do I get the content to appear properly without resizing the page?

Here is roughly what my code looks like, in a phtml file:

```
   <div id="div_for_simplemodal" style="display:none"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 *script that generates content*
            </script>
```

Then, in a separate JS file:

```
    $("#div_for_simplemodal").modal({overlayClose:true});
```

And the CSS:

```
  #simplemodal-container {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1200px;
    color: #bbb;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 4px solid #444;
    padding: 12px; }
```

Again, the simplemodal-container appears fine, but without the content that my javascript is supposed to generate. The content appears on the page and in the container without "display:none" added to "div_for_simplemodal", and appears in the container after I resize the page.

Comment: the jquery selector is different from the div id div_for_simple_modal !== div_for_simplemodal

Answer (score 1):

You have used the selector `$("#div_for_simple_modal")` which doesn't match the ID of the element.

Use `$('#div_for_simplemodal');`

Comment: Oops! You're right, but that was just a typo I made when I posted this. (The div in my actual code isn't called "div_for_simplemodal").  I fixed it here.